# Compare between two dates in SQL query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have a table, `roomtype`, with the following data:

```
Hotel_ID    Name     Rate   Season    StartSeason   EndSeason
   1      Deluxe/Ac  2700   New Year  2013-12-20    2014-01-10
   1      Deluxe/Ac  3100   31 Dec    2013-12-31    2012-12-31
   1      Deluxe/Ac  1700   Diwali    2013-11-01    2013-11-15
   1      Deluxe/Ac  800    Normal    NULL          NULL
```

For a given date (ie, `2013-11-09`), I want to return the `rate` for the matching season, where the given date falls within the StartSeason and EndSeason dates.

ie, If my date is `2013-11-09`, then the rate should be 1700.
If my date is `2012-09-09`, then the rate should be 800.

How do I create a stored procedure or write the SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select top 1 hotel_id, rate
from roomtype r
where '2013-11-09' between startseason and endseason
or startseason is null and endseason is null
order by case when startseason is null and endseason is null then 2 else 1 end
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve the hard work of the query optimizer you can help him uses the UNION ALL operator inside subquery

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM Table1
      WHERE @date BETWEEN StartSeason AND EndSeason
      UNION ALL
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM Table1
      WHERE StartSeason IS NULL
      ) x
ORDER BY StartSeason DESC
```

Of course, in addition to this query, it would be great provide the correct index

```
CREATE INDEX x ON Table1(StartSeason)
  INCLUDE(EndSeason,Hotel_ID,Name,Rate,Season)
```

Plan Diagram

[image]

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08409/8)

Answer (score 0):

This should supply you with just the rate matching the season for the date in your query:

```
SELECT rate FROM roomtype 
   WHERE StartSeason >= '2013-11-09' AND EndSeason <= '2013-11-09';
```

Comment: +1 for the other answer, I didn't factor in the `null <> null` season :)